# Login with retrofit third party lib

Tags: android

http://localhost/shop/api2/login.php?email=xxxx@gmail.com&password=xxxxx

{"success":1,"customer_id":"2","customer_group_id":"0","email":"tanaji@gmail.com"}

```
 private void attemptLogin(final String email, final String password) {

         Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                 .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                 .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.14/shop/api2/")
                 .build();
         LoginApi service = retrofit.create(LoginApi.class);
            User user = new User();
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setPassword(password);

         Call<ResponseBody> userCall = service.login(email,password);
         userCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
             @Override
             public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                 ResponseBody resp = response.body();
                if (resp != null && resp.equals(1)) {

                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Response"+response.body(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                     Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                     startActivity(in);
                 }

             }
             @Override
             public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         });


                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null && response.body().getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
```

.getStatus is not working in my code.

and if success: 1 then its want login and then open to new page.

how to get json resopnse successfully?

Comment: you should check like resp.getSuccess().equlaingnorecase("1"); if your  ResponseBody model class conatin getter and setter for success.

Answer (score 0):

Make ResponseBody Model

```
public class ResponseBody
{
private String customer_group_id;

private String email;

private String success;

private String customer_id;

public String getCustomer_group_id ()
{
    return customer_group_id;
}

public void setCustomer_group_id (String customer_group_id)
{
    this.customer_group_id = customer_group_id;
}

public String getEmail ()
{
    return email;
}

public void setEmail (String email)
{
    this.email = email;
}

public String getSuccess ()
{
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess (String success)
{
    this.success = success;
}

public String getCustomer_id ()
{
    return customer_id;
}

public void setCustomer_id (String customer_id)
{
    this.customer_id = customer_id;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [customer_group_id = "+customer_group_id+", email = 
"+email+", success = "+success+", customer_id = "+customer_id+"]";
}
}
```

Call Retrofit

```
  Call<ResponseBody> userCall = service.login(email,password);
 userCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

      if(response.body()!=null)
         if(response.body(). 
        getSuccess().contains("1"){

                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
        "Response"+response.body(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
         ProfileActivity.class);
             startActivity(in);


         }

     }
     @Override
     public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
 });
```